# Answering multiple questions in a single post

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700098/whats-is-difference-between-dependency-inversion-and-separated-interface-pattern/20700241#20700284), well there is more than one question hidden in there.  Firstly the obvious one, difference between DI and Separated Interfaces.  There's also a package management question in there, as to where to put the interfaces and why.

These are both good questions but should we be answering multiple questions in a single post because like the comment says, it's a little lengthy.  How should we deal with it if not?

I'm tempted to continue this onto "Is there functionality to split a question in two? if not, should there be?" but that would be ironically asking two questions in one post

Comment: Closing as too broad with a comment suggesting a split is how I deal with these

Answer (score 3):

When coming across a question with multiple (only vaguely related) questions within it I will usually vote to close as too broad and leave a comment explaining that one question should be asked individually.

This is important  because an answer may give an excellent answer to one sub question but a terrible answer to another. Under these circumstances the voting system breaks down